# Handling high-impedance (open) state of CMOS

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl5Gsem.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hobbyist here, looking for some help with a problem I have been having. I have an automotive application where I'm trying to tap into an existing wire from the OEM harness (A in the diagram).

That wire can be in one of three states based on a couple of factors which are not important. The wire can be +12 V, grounded, or open. If the wire is +12 V I need to activate one circuit (C in the diagram), if the wire is grounded I need to active a different circuit (B in the diagram), and if the wire is open I need neither of the previous circuits activated.

The solution I came up with was to use an NMOS and PMOS to control the activation of the other circuits. However, the problem I ran into was that in the open state, the MOSFET gates retain their previous charge and do not shut off the other circuits.

This led me to add pull up and pull down resistors as can be seen in the diagram. This, of course, does not work as this activates both MOSFETs when A is open. I have tried a whole mess of things with diodes and voltages dividers with little luck.

I am in no way tied to using MOSFETs or the attached schematic if there is a better way of achieving the above goals. I appreciate any help or ideas.

Comment: Maybe some bjts and zener diodes at a pinch? If you use pmos and nmos to describe p or n channel mosfets, most engineers will look at you strangely. Where did you get such a description?

Comment: Most ic design engineers do call them pmos or nmos devices or nfet or pfet for short. The name here likely comes from the library assigned label.

Comment: @Kartman sorry if that is not the correct term.  I saw that sprinkled all over the internet when searching for solutions to this.  I just assumed that was the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a pain but you can bias the output to mid-voltage with and then use what is essentially a 3-level flash ADC to trigger stuff.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzvkD7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Neat solution. I think you could get rid of the middle comparators by instead feeding the output of the outer ones into a NOR gate, right? Or is that just as complex? (I don't know how NOR gates are actually implemented). Edit: nvm, I now see you have those to deal with the hysterisis

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom Maybe? I'm pretty tired was actively trying to not just stop the drawing. I just don't want to think about it tonight.

Comment: Well I would say that generally speaking, your solution is preferable. OP might prefer always having a defined output (i.e. exactly one of them on) though, even if it could become hysterical. But that doesn't seem a likely requirement.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom I mean, yeah, depends what you want.

Comment: @DKNguyen thank you for this.  I think this should work

Comment: @neoskunk You may need to make R4 and R5 larger than R6 so the CMOS logic HI and logic low levels fall into the proper range.